# Parallelize this code

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am trying to figure out how to parallelize the following code.
I have looked up `joblib`, `concurrent.futures`, and `multiprocessing` modules, but cannot for the life of me figure out how they work from reading the docs and scouring SO/google.

`Grid` is a class object with the appropriate methods defined and it does not matter what order the loop is processed.

```
def ProcessGrid(Grid):
    #Parallel This Loop
    for i in range(len(Grid)):
        Grid[i].AdjustCostMultiplier()
        Grid[i].FindAllNeighbours(Grid)
        print("Processing Grid Cell: " + str(i) + " of " + str(len(Grid)),end = "\r")
    #Return to serial
    return Grid
```

Comment: Do you want to call the ProcessGrid method 2 times parallel? Or do you want to call AdjustCostMultiplier() and FindAllNeighbours()?

Comment: I want to parallelize the for loop, I'll edit my question to reflect the clarification

Comment: "Do X for me" requests (it's hard to describe them as "questions") don't tend to get a good response here without at least showing your own effort -- not just asserting that you tried, but actually showing the code you wrote in the form of a [mcve] and describing how it fails.

Comment: Alright, I added an answer. I didn't test it tho but it should work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the threading library like this:

```
import threading

def process(grid, i):
    grid[i].AdjustCostMultiplier()
    grid[i].FindAllNeighbours(Grid)
    print("Processing Grid Cell: " + str(i) + " of " + str(len(grid)), end = "\r")

def ProcessGrid(Grid):
    threads = []
    for i in range(len(Grid)):
        t = threading.Thread(target=process, args=(Grid, i))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        # Wait for all threads to finish
        t.join()
    #Return to serial
    return Grid
```

`process()` will be called in a new thread for every iteration. `t.join()` then waits for the threads to finish.

Comment: Python multi-threading does not make code faster when it is CPU bound, unfortunately, because of the Global Interpreter Lock. Multiprocessing does make it faster, but it will take a bit more effort.

Comment: He asked to parallelize it tho. He never asked to make his code faster. Also multithreading can make code faster if there is a waiting process involved.

Comment: there was some issues with t being "NoneType' (I guess because of no return statements?), but I just commented out the join statement and it worked fine for my case

Comment: oops, sorry I fixed it. I stored .start() into t instead of the thread itself. Just move t.start() into the line below.

Comment: @Maarten_vd_Sande Parallelizing can make code faster if (a) it's not CPU-bound, or (b) it is CPU-bpund. but most of that work is inside C extension libraries that release the GIL for major operations, like numpy, or (c) it's run in a GIL-less Python interpreter like Jython.